# How to make/generate/extract quickly shapefiles of different countires?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins, administrative-boundaries

How one can easily make/geenrate/extract the shapefile of countries or any shapefile quickly in QGIS? Is there any plugins to execute the administrative of countries within a minute?

Comment: Using the proper tags you may download them from OSM.

Comment: QGIS Plugin for that is QuickOSM, you'll need to look at the OSM tags and define the appropriate rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need the country borders type `world` in the coordinates box, enter, right click the layer and export:

[image]